# Appending indexes from list not working correctly

Tags: python, list, append, repeat

I am attempting to take the indexes of blank/empty spaces within a list ('') and append those into a new list. However, when I do so, it only appends the first index over and over again.

```
for line in line_list:
        if line == '':
            tlist.append(line_list.index(line))
```

I know this fix must be incredibly simple but it's been frustrating me all afternoon.

printing tlist gives me [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3.......]

Comment: It would be helpful if you tagged what language you are trying to do this in.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

The `index()` function is returning the index of the *first* occurrence of the value,so it won't work. Try this instead, using a list comprehension makes more sense, and `enumerate()` will tell you the index of each element:

```
tlist = [idx for idx, line in enumerate(line_list) if line == '']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index()` function in Python returns only the FIRST occurrence of the element specified. As a result, you will only append the index of the first occurrence of a blank element to `tlist`. Instead, use the `enumerate` function with it, which allows you to loop with the index number in a variable as well.

```
for index, line in enumerate(line_list):
    if line == '':
        tlist.append(index)
```

Alternatively, you can use a `while` loop, which I would personally recommend instead of using `enumerate` with the `for each` loop. Here

```
index = 0
while index < len(line_list):
    line = line_list[index]
    if line == '':
        tlist.append(index)
    index += 1
```

Whichever method you choose is up to you, they both work well.